# How to make a horizontal scrollable UITabBar in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

The UITabBar in my app consists of 10+ items, but the width is enough to put all 10+ items.

How to make a horizontal scrollable UITabBar in iOS ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you please help me in implementing this solution if it worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own to at least some extent.

What ***might*** work, would be to create a UITabBar view (not the controller) and embedded it in a UIScrollView. You could then use that in place of your regular Tab Bar control by adding it to your TabBarController.view/tabBarView or something. Of course you'd have to play around to get it to look right, and I'm not sure if just setting the view to something wider will actually make it display more items or not.

Of course, for best results you'd probably want to do something entirely custom.

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's Developer Portal:

> If you add more than five items to the viewControllers property, the tab bar controller automatically inserts a special view controller (called the More view controller) to handle the display of the additional items.
>   [Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html)

Seems like you will need to make a custom tab bar.

They also said this in the next paragraph:

> Although the tab bar view is a key part of your tab bar interface, you do not modify that view directly.
>   You might be breaking Apple's design guidelines by doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly go and create a custom class of the UITabBar (embedding it into a scrollview etc.)..but why re-invent the wheel? After searching around I found several third-party classes already created that work well and are easy to use and highly customizable..In order of personal preference:

M13InfiniteTabBar - 
https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar

JSScrollableTabBar - 
https://github.com/jasarien/JSScrollableTabBar

InfiniTabBar - 
https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar

Comment: I can't find anything in Swift. Looking for a Infinite TabBar but pinned on top which will load web view and also recognise gesture.